# Docker .NET 5.0 API cannot connect to external or containerd database

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have this architecture on my host OS. It consist of three individual container running on my host OS (Windows 10).

[image: dockerarchitecture]

My .NET 5.0 API cannot reach my SQL Server 2019 whether my local SQL Server or containerd SQL Server.

If i run this API in VS Studio everything just works. The moment i put the image in a container if can't reach both SQL Servers...

This is my ConnectionString:

```json
"ConnectionString": {
          "DemoDB": "server=127.0.0.1,1433;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;database=DemoDB;User ID=user;password=xxx"
    },
```

```
# Here, we include the dotnet core SDK as the base to build our app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine AS build-env
# Setting the work directory for our app
WORKDIR /app

# We copy the .csproj of our app to root and 
# restore the dependencies of the project.
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore 

# Once we're done building, we'll publish the project
# to the publish folder 
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine 
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
EXPOSE 5000
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DemoAppBackend.dll"]
```

Here is my LaunchSetting.json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44340",
      "sslPort": 44340
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DemoAppBackend": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried to run my docker container with the `--net=host` flag and accepted all inbound traffic from docker in my firewall, but this does not resolve my issue.

Comment: You should use `docker compose` to place your container in one network

Comment: Yeah indeed after talking to a another senior, he also advised to compose this all in one file